# Giving Dynamic Element values to jquery $('#element')

Tags: jquery

I have a list of items where each list has a contact form, which gets displayed dynamically and submits the form. What I want when submitting, the JavaScript will get the form number, and I want the success message to displayed inside that particular form only...

```
Form 1 - message_1
Form 3 - message_2
Form 3 - message_3
```

I have the form number say `frmno = 1`, so, can I do like this:

```
$("#message_" + frmno).html // this seems like not working, if not working what could be another way..

$("#message").html("<h3>Your Message was successfully submitted!</h3>")
```

Comment: Any errors? Can you show us the actual HTML/Code? Would be very helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

> ...which gets displayed dynamically and submits the form

If it *really* submits the form, then you'll want to handle this server-side, because submitting the form will tear down the current page and replace it with what you return from the form submission.

But if you're submitting via ajax, then provided the `form` elements actually have `id` values (rather than or in addition to `name`s) in the form `message_1`, etc., then your first line:

```
$("#message_" + frmno).html("your html here");
```

...should be working, provided the elements in question already exist in the DOM (and of course, they do, if the user's been filling in a form).

Example - below I'm getting the form number from the value of a button, but the concept is the same; note that I'm using `jQuery(function)`, which is a shortcut for [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) that waits to do something until the DOM is complete:

HTML:

```
<input type='button' value='Set 1'>
<input type='button' value='Set 2'>
<input type='button' value='Set 3'>
<form id='message_1'>This is div 1</form>
<form id='message_2'>This is div 2</form>
<form id='message_3'>This is div 3</form>
```

JavaScript using jQuery:

```
jQuery(function() {

  $(':button').click(function() {
    var index = this.value.replace('Set ', '');
    $('#message_' + index).html("Div " + index + " updated at " + new Date());
  });

});​
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ujeki/2)